# Error while filtering a list of strings based on contents - python

Tags: python, arrays, split

I am having an array 'commit'  with following values and have country list in seprate array - Self.Countries (UNITED STATES, CHINA, GERMANY).

```
commit = [['UNITED_STATES-Consumer1_SymPercChg'],
          ['UNITED_STATES-Housing1_StndDev'],
          ['UNITED_STATES-Auto1_SymPercChg'],
          ['CHINA-Finance1_SymPercChg'],
          ['CHINA-Transport1_StndDev'],
          ['CHINA-Housing1_SymPercChg'],
          ['GERMANY-PMI1_StndDev'],
          ['GERMANY-Manufacturing1_SymPercChg'],
          ['GERMANY-Survey1_SymPercChg']
         ]
```

I need help in splitting the array 'commmit' based on the countries list. I tried below code but its not working. Its returning a empty list:

```
    for country in self.countries:
        self.select_columns = [x for x in commit if country in x]
```

Comment: You don't have `array` in python, you have `list`.

Comment: Use this list comprehension instead `[x for x in commit if x.startswith(country)]`

Comment: Please specify output which you want to get.

Comment: For UNITED_STATES , I need three values - UNITED_STATES-Consumer1_SymPercChg,
UNITED_STATES-Housing1_StndDev,
UNITED_STATES-Auto1_SymPercChg. Similar approach for other countries .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've countries with multi word countries name separated by space(in your question) and not `_`.

You could do something like:

```
countries = ['UNITED STATES',
            'CHINA',
            'GERMANY'
            ]
commit = [['UNITED_STATES-Consumer1_SymPercChg'],
      ['UNITED_STATES-Housing1_StndDev'],
      ['UNITED_STATES-Auto1_SymPercChg'],
      ['CHINA-Finance1_SymPercChg'],
      ['CHINA-Transport1_StndDev'],
      ['CHINA-Housing1_SymPercChg'],
      ['GERMANY-PMI1_StndDev'],
      ['GERMANY-Manufacturing1_SymPercChg'],
      ['GERMANY-Survey1_SymPercChg']
     ]
for c in countries:
    c = "_".join(c.split(" "))
    print c, [x for x in commit if c in x[0]]
```

Output:

```
UNITED_STATES ['UNITED_STATES-Consumer1_SymPercChg', 'UNITED_STATES-Housing1_StndDev', 'UNITED_STATES-Auto1_SymPercChg']


CHINA ['CHINA-Finance1_SymPercChg', 'CHINA-Transport1_StndDev', 'CHINA-Housing1_SymPercChg']

GERMANY ['GERMANY-PMI1_StndDev', 'GERMANY-Manufacturing1_SymPercChg', 'GERMANY-Survey1_SymPercChg']
```

Comment: Made changes to the question.Sorry! I having array values inside a array. I am still getting empty list as output.

Comment: @ArvinthKumar Ah. You've list of lists eh? I wonder why. Modified the code now.

Comment: Its still not working. I am having values in this format [ [], [], [] ] . Please help.

Comment: @ArvinthKumar Ah . My bad . Can you check now please . [demo](https://repl.it/repls/MenacingAlarmingFtpclient)

Answer (score 1):

Try a [regex match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(^[A-Z_]+)(-)(.+)')
country_data = {}

for c in commit:
    match = pattern.match(c[0])
    if match:
        if match.group(1) in countries:
            if match.group(1) in country_data.keys():
                country_data[match.group(1)].append(match.string)
            else:
                country_data[match.group(1)] = [match.string]

print(country_data)
```

Comment: Made changes to the question.Sorry! I having array values inside a array. I am still getting empty list as output.

Comment: Please provide the full code you are using as I still don't understand what you need.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my code to deal with your list of lists input. This solution will return a dictionary of lists tied to countries that you can work with.

Why you need a list of lists containing a single string value I do not know. Ideally we avoid unnecessary nesting of data structures.